# Add tag to a map of tags where the tag key is dymamic

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

In a Cloudformation template, is it possible to use functions in to construct tag keys?

For some reason, tags for the `AWS::EKS::Nodegroup` type are different to every other resource (that I have had to use), so rather than tags being formatted like this...

```
Tags:
  - Key: TagKey
  - Value: TagValue
```

...they have to be formatted like this...

```
Tags:
  TagKey: TagValue
```

That's all well and good if `TagKey` is static, but when it's value depends on the value of an incoming parameter, I'm not sure how to add the tag.

I've tried the obvious, hoping that `!Sub` would be run against any key names with `${}`, but that fails -

```
Tags:
  k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/${ClusterName}: owned
```

> null (Service: AmazonEKS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 4bc0257f-6fed-40e2-905e-7e4cda022313; Proxy: null)

Is there a way to do this with CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly its not possible. You would have to create your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) in cloudformation for such a functionality.

Comment: Well that makes me sad :(
It's the only resource where I need to do such a thing, and it's the only resource I've come across what expects tags formatted in this way. Poor effort on many fronts by AWS.